# Flatlist inside a function in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I create an flatlist and add items to it inside a function not a class in react native?? all of the examples online are using classes and I need to use it inside a function !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example of a FlatList in the React Native docs that is using a functional component:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

If you just want the code check out the same example on snack:

https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-R6Nsz_Qm1&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=uetjvvask3&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=flatlist-simple&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true

I hope it helped :)

Comment: This helped alot....thank you so much :) especially the first link

Answer (score 0):

Same as with any other component, there's not much difference between using a `FlatList` inside a class vs a function. Only the state handling changes a little bit.

The code below will render all items, you'll be able to press on any of them to duplicate the item which should then show up at the bottom of the list.

```js
export const FlatListScreen = props => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

    function duplicateItem(toDuplicate) {
        setItems(prev => [...prev, toDuplicate]);
    }

    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={items}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => duplicateItem(item)}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>
                            {item}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )}  
        />
    );
}
```